# On iOS, if a superview's userInteractionEnabled is NO, then all subviews are disabled as well?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit, uiresponder

I thought when a view is touched or tapped on, its handler get called first, and then its superview's handler is called (propagate upward).

But is it true that if the superview's `userInteractionEnabled` is set to NO, then all subviews and offspring is also disabled for user interaction?  What if we want to disable for just the main view but don't want to disable for the subviews?

Comment: aha, I was wondering what rule or what mechanism of the UIResponder causes this... even though right now I memorize this as a "fact"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do that,

Instead you would change the arrangment of your views like following:

```
Main View -> subViews
```

To

```
Container View -> Main View that you want to set as inactive
               -> other views that you want to still be active
```

So your current main view and you current subviews will become siblings, children of a new container view

Comment: "cant do that" What is "that"? Which part of the question are you referring to?

Answer (score 39):

You can override `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` to ignore the view itself, but still deliver touches to its subviews.

```
class ContainerStackView : UIStackView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let result = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if result == self { return nil }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good. Solves a lot of problems. I used it to get an Navigation bar that's passes through touches without ignoring the buttons. I modified this to: "return result is UIControl ? result : nil"

Comment: Very good and clean solution. Works perfectly

Answer (score 29):

If this may be helpful, I found this in Programming iOS 5 by Matt Neuburg, p. 467:

> `userInteractionEnabled`
>
> If set to NO, this view (along with its subviews) is excluded from
>   receiving touches.  Touches  on this view or one of its subviews "fall
>   through" to a view behind it.

Further more, Apple's Event Handling Guide for iOS says:

> The window object uses hit-testing and the responder chain to find the
>   view to receive the touch event. In hit-testing, a window calls
>   hitTest:withEvent: on the top-most view of the view hierarchy; this
>   method proceeds by recursively calling pointInside:withEvent: on each
>   view in the view hierarchy that returns YES, proceeding down the
>   hierarchy until it finds the subview within whose bounds the touch
>   took place. That view becomes the hit-test view.

and Programming iOS 5 by Matt Neuburg, p.485 mentioned that if a view is marked `userInteractionEnabled` as `NO`, or `hidden` as `YES`, or opacity is close to 0, then the view and its subview will not be traversed by `HitTest` (and therefore not considered for any touch).

Updated: I suppose it also works this way if we think about parent-child situation in other scenario. For example, in HTML, if there is a `div` and there are children all under this `div`, and now this `div` is set to `display: none`, then it makes sense that all the children are not displayed as well. So if a parent is set to not interact with the user, it also makes sense that the children do not interact with the user as well.

Comment: Excellent info for those people implementing their own `hitTest:withEvent:`. I wasn't sure whether I needed to check `if(subview.userInteractionEnabled)` at the superview level, but it appears the default implementation checks its own `userInteractionEnabled` property.'

Comment: what does 
"fall through" to a view behind it." mean? Does that mean tapping on buttons that are subviews won't work?

Answer (score 3):

**First Method**

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[SuperViewParent class]]) return FALSE;
  return TRUE;
}
```

**Second Method**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *r = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(agentPickerTapped:)];
    r.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [agentPicker addGestureRecognizer:r];
```