# UIButton Touch Down not Registering in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I have created a UIButton on the Interface Builder (Main.storyboard). I Connected two actions to the View Controller swift file, as you can see below:

```
@IBAction func backDownPress(sender: UIButton) {
    backButon.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
@IBAction func backNormalPress(sender: UIButton) {
    backButon.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pushFromRight", sender: self)
}
```

The top action is a Touch Down, and the bottom is a Touch up Inside.

However, once I try to run the app on either the Simulator or my iPhone, the touch doesn't register. When I try to just put a print line in the action, it also doesn't do anything.

Looking through the rest of my code, I can't find anything like disabling the user interaction, so I don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: can you code the uibuttons programatically? just an opinion but for me i prefer code since it is more stale for me

Answer (score 2):

Well there are 2 possible solutions to this:

1) The @IBAction is not connected to the button.

2) There is something layered in front of the Button (a view of some kind)

Answer (score 0):

I m guessing you want to change button color when pressed.

**1. Subclass UIButton and implement**

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
            else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IBAction connections are proper:
Check the userInteractionEnabled property for superview as subView's user interaction depends on superview as well.
Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880868/on-ios-if-a-superviews-userinteractionenabled-is-no-then-all-subviews-are-dis) link.