# Disable `userInteractionEnabled` for UIView but selectively allow interaction for a sub view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'd like to disable touch handling for a UIView but keep it enabled for one of its subviews.

The problem is once I set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the parent view, I can't bring it back by explicitly setting it to true in a sub view.

How can I enable `userInteractionEnabled` selectively just for one sub view?

Comment: you can't do this if you disabled userInteraction on superview .http://stackoverflow.com/a/10881013/3901620

Comment: Create a custom UIView class and implement `hitTest`as in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios